# Django REST AttributeError 'dict' object has no attribute 'pk'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to create a REST API with Django REST Framework. The issue I'm experiencing is `dict` object has no attribute `pk` when I try to display aggregated data. I can see in the traceback that `serializer.data` displayed as it should be, the format is as follows:

```
[{'maint_window':'W1-12:00-CET', 'total':'10'},
 {'maint_window':'W2-12:00-CET', 'total':'5',}
 {'maint_window':'W3-12:00-CET', 'total':'22'}]
```

But it seems that I'm not returning the correct format in the view, or in the serializer.

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Server(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    fqdn = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    maint_window = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

serializers.py:

```
 class ServerSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
     class Meta:
         model = Server
         fielsds='__all__'
```

views.py:

```
class OpsCalendarViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
"""
API endpoint that shows ops calendar
"""
queryset = Server.objects \
          .filter(~Q(maint_window__contains='MW') & \
                  ~Q(maint_window__contains='Change') & \
                  ~Q(maint_window__contains='Individual')) \
          .values('maint_window') \
          .annotate(total=Count('name'))\
          .order_by('maint_window')
serializer_class = ServerSerializer
permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]
```

And the error itself:

```
lookup_value = getattr(obj, self.lookup_field)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'pk'
```

Comment: You are performing a ***group by*** operation and it's returning a ***`dict`*** object, not a `QuerySet`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, should I override the list method?

Comment: try removing `values`. You might want to replace it with `only`.

Comment: Sorry but only() does not return the correct values

Comment: Your ServerSerializer is a `ModelSerializer` that is instructed to serialize `__all__` the fields on the model. That is, you should provide it with an instance of the model to have to have it serialize as expected. Instead you are attempting to serialize a dictionary with expected values missing.

Comment: Hi, now I get it Thanks